# Installing Apps on Offline Ubuntu PCs

Tags: offline

I have seen similar questions but they neither are clear, nor had the exact answer I am looking for.

Is there a way to install a program with all dependencies (+ dependencies of dependencies etc.) on an offline and freshly installed Ubuntu? (regardless of the version)

Please don't recommend me to find a way to get online on that specific PC. And if you don't know the answer, please don't write anything. Thanks.

Note: I have access to the internet somewhere else :)

Comment: How you do it can vary on the type of package, the Ubuntu system you're asking about, and details you've not provided. Some Ubuntu systems for example are *deb* package based, some are *snap* package only.. with difference existing between the types of packages (eg. *snap*, *deb* *appimage*, *flatpak* let alone from source).  There is no one clear answer that fits all.   (Ubuntu Core systems have the simplest as they can only use *snap* packages being more limited to other systems that have many package choices)

Comment: You can make packages for offline install using Synaptic.